# Pip freeze and pip list show no output at all regardless of venv, pip install works

Tags: python, pip

I am having a bit of an issue trying to get pip freeze or list to work.

On Windows in VSCode with a git bash terminal I created a new venv and then activated it.

I then updated pip.

Installing packages with pip install uvicorn works no problem.

Where pip and where python show the environment path first (on top) as it should be.
However, neither pip freeze now pip list give any output. The python version is 3.12.0

For the record, pip list and freeze do not work without any environment either, so I suspect this is a global problem. It is a clean installation of python (deinstalled 3.11. installed 3.12. and I am not sure whether I had the same problem before).

Anything else I can try?

Comment: It sounds like you might have used a different instance of pip when installing the module, and now you're using another one when running `pip freeze`. Try `pip --version` to get the path of the pip binary if you haven't already.

Comment: I have and I made sure I used it when creating the venv. I even deleted and reinstalled a venv and then a package. The packages installed are also correctly in the env lib.